# Custom content printing in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, printing, uikit

I am a new bee to iphone programming and I need some help with printing.

I have a view with UIScrollView,UITextView and UIImage as its subviews. I would like to print this view such that the complete content of the scroll view and text view will available be available on the printed page. I went through the UIPrintFormatter but I am not sure of how to use it for my requirement. It would be really great if someone could give me a good answer(example\sample code) for my problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came randomly to this question. No answer yet! Little help from code,

```
- (void) didPressPrintExpenseButton {
    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);
    };

    NSData *pdfData = [self generatePDFDataForPrinting];
    printController.printingItem = pdfData;
    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```